# Find files by modified, only return root folder, ignore folder timestamps

Tags: powershell

Just need some help to point me in the right direction.

We have a volume w/ 4000+ root folders *windows file server*. Each folder can have a very deep hierarchy. Goal is to output a list of the **root folders** that contains files within that have not been modified in 3years, search all depth's, and ignore all FOLDER timestamps. And return just the root folder where those files exist.

can someone point me in the right direction. get-childitem?

Ignore Folder/Directory timestamps, find files not modified in 3yrs, search entire depth of each root folder, return just the root folder where those files exist.

I don't know powershell, but trying to learn.

First Pass

```
$archive = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1095)

Get-ChildItem -Recurse  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $archive} | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv C:\Users\test\Documents\olddata.csv
```

Couple of questions - I want to reference back to the 'root folder' which would be P:\MAIN\RootFolder1...... P:\MAIN\RootFolder2......

So for each RootFolder: Search all files (recurse) find LastWriteTime more recent than 3yrs. I don't need it to search the whole path, as soon as it finds any file, located at any depth under a RootFolder, more recent than 3yrs - move on to next RootFolder. If you do not find anything more recent than 3yrs - output RootFolder name.

Thank you,

Comment: Get-Childitem has a switch -file which outputs only files. You can filter with Where-Object on the lastmodified property. Finally you can select the psparent property of your output to get the folders where the files reside (for which you can sort on unique folders). That is the basic flow of a script you can build for this.

Comment: PowerShell is easy to learn. Start by reading the documentation on `Get-ChildItem`. Then practice with a few of examples from the Internet. Stackoverflow does not write code for you. We will try to help you with code that YOU write. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7 https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-get-childitem/

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` is really rather slow for REALLY LARGE file counts - and may error out for deep dir structures. i would use `robocopy` with the `list only` option and the ` /MINAGE:n` option. you can then save the listing to a log file & parse that ... or ave to a $Var in PoSh and parse that.